# How to remove separator from tableview?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.1

I used interface builder and changed my `tableview` style as grouped and separator as none.

I was able to see the change in the display style which is grouped right now. But the separator change is not getting reflected.

How to remove the separator?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286332/how-do-i-remove-the-borders-of-a-uitableview

Answer (score 3):

Ok - Just do this.

If you have rootViewController, in viewDidLoad method - just place following line.
 ( Default view controller in "Navigation based application")

Whatever view controller you have to place following code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // if it your view controller extends - UITableViewController
    [self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        // or 
        // your placed tableVCtr on .xib & have datasource & delegate & table connections
        [mytableVCtr setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I actually referred the link sent by warrior.

Answer (score 0):

[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];