# Is it possible to remove the black line which separates the rows in a tablecell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How can I do this? I want the cells appear like just a collection of items with no separations in the form of lines?

And also how can I make the contentView of a cell go transparent?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286332/how-do-i-remove-the-borders-of-a-uitableview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use plain style then:
To remove lines: `tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;`
To make the contentView of a cell go transparent: `set backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]` in anything you can set (tableView, cell, cell.contentView).