# Show only the first row in a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, storyboard

So, most of the questions are "my tableView only shows the first row, what's wrong?".
Well, what I need is exactly the opposite.

I have a `SearchBar` (not `Search Display Controller`) and until the user starts typing, I want to show ONLY the first row and nothing more.

My `TableView`'s content is `Dynamic Prototypes`, with 2 `Prototype Cells`.
The first is the only one I want to show, but it shows others in blank.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4ak6z3gbc0gh5c/Screenshot%202014-07-22%2011.24.22.png

This is my `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSInteger numberOfRows = 0;

    if ([self.searchBar.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        numberOfRows = 1;
    }

    return numberOfRows;
}
```

All the help will be very appreciated! \o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view controller's `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` make sure `tableView` equals to `self.tableView`, and then you return 1:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return yourDataModel.count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I did, but your screenshot only shows a simulator with only one cell in the table view, which can be achieved exactly in this way.

Comment: @edmoks If you meant hiding the separator between cells, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286332/how-do-i-remove-the-borders-of-a-uitableview

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is a better solution, but as proposed before :

```
CGRect frame = [self.tableView frame];

frame.size.height = [self tableView:self.tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];

self.tableView.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must change the size UITableView's contentView or frame at the creation (alloc).

This height must be the same of an UITableViewCell by default (44px) or custom.

Answer (score 0):

Write the below 4 lines to make a table with one row. If you want to extend the content of the table just make the tableview scrollable.

```
tblView                     = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
tblView.separatorColor      = [UIColor clearColor];
tblView.tableFooterView     = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];    
tblView.scrollEnabled       = NO;
```